# Is it possible to change the frequency of an audio?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-effects-recording, signal-processing, voice-manipulation

If I record myself singing, can I change the frequency of the audio signal that is generated and listen to it at any frequency? If so, how can I do that? Is there any software available?

Comment: You need to be little more descriptive and clear. Do you want to 
1. change the pitch of the whole audio? – pitch shift/transposition
2. change pitch of parts of recording? – AutoTune
3. change the timbre of the vocals? – Vocoder

Comment: Okay. 'The voiced speech of a typical adult male will have a fundamental frequency from 85 to 180 Hz, and that of a typical adult female from 165 to 255 Hz '(source : Wikipedia - Voice frequency). Suppose , I record someone speaking at,say, a frequency of 150 Hz, will be able to record the speech and increase the frequency to,say 500 Hz?

Comment: People don't speak at a 'frequency'. Speech is made up of multiple frequency components. How you handle the combination of frequency components will depend entirely on what you want to achieve and whether you want to retain the fundamental or not.

Comment: @Shield_maiden this is basic pitch shifting in action - https://youtu.be/58WKiHVPFMY?t=212. Is this what you want to achieve? If it is then you need to specify in which software you want to do it. Be as specific and precise as possible for better understanding.